Why should I use opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter, and which method should be used instead?
I have a question related to integrating Spring Boot with OpenTelemetry. I am planning to use the dependency opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter. My questions are:  When should I use this approach?
Why shouldn't I use the Java Agent instead?
What is the difference between these methods, and which one should I choose?

If you are already using Spring Boot, there's no question that you should prefer the Spring Boot starter to anything else.    They are better software engineers than you or I will ever be.   They have already tested their starter code thoroughly.   You'll get upgrades as they improve it.   Prefer the Spring Boot code over your own.

Similar question with context that may be helpful.
I'm a fan of using OpenTelemetry because  it "just works". Spring has done all of the integration work to let us get our base cases for observability done.
